# Function opens too fast after a timeout in javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am trying to make a Tapermonkeyscript, but someway the function opens itself way to often - it should do it every second - start and end are time stamps, so somehow the timeout isn't working right and I don't see the problem - can anyone please help?

```
function redefine(a) {
  var start = parent.mainFrame.start; //get start
  var end = parent.mainFrame.end; //get end
  var points = new Array(1, 2, 6, 3, 7, 3, 5, 3); //set array
  if (end - start <= 1) { //check if ready
    parent.mainFrame.setPoint(points[a]); //redefine point
    a = a + 1; //nextpoint
  }
  window.setTimeout(redefine(a), 1000); //check again in 1s for points
}
redefine(0);
```

Regards,
basicn00b

Comment: you should pass function reference,`window.setTimeout(function(){redefine(a)}, 1000); `

Comment: @FastSnail and his function is inside timeout . will that cause problem ?

Comment: It will most certainly cause the problem. Since the function is not passed by reference but executed. It will call `redefine` at the end of every `redefine` call, causing an infinite loop. @FastSnail I suggest you post an answer.

Comment: probably duplicate let's close it

Comment: Preferably, you should use an array literal `[1, 2, 6, 3, 7, 3, 5, 3]` rather than using the `Array` constructor.

Comment: thanks for your help!